# What is the fundamental units for coulomb?

Tags: units, si-units, unit-conversion

Everything I saw suggests coulomb has no fundamental units.
So then how is Newton/Coulomb equivalent to Volt/meter?

Comment: A Coulomb *is* the SI unit of electric charge

Comment: But how can you convert N/C to V/M?

Comment: voltage = energy/charge so $1\mathrm{V} = 1 \mathrm{JC}^{-1}$. Work = force * distance so $1\mathrm{N} = 1\mathrm{Jm}^{-1}$

Comment: Closely related: [Why is the Ampere a base unit and not the Coulomb?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/70651/).

Comment: Also, on EE.SE: [Why is current (and not charge) an SI base unit?](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/62483/)

Answer (score 7):

The coulomb (C) is the *derived* unit for charge in SI. One coulomb is the amount of charge in one ampere-second. The elementary charge (charge of one proton or (-) electron) is roughly ${\sim}1.602\times10^{-19}\:\mathrm C.$ Moreover, $1\:\mathrm C =1\:\mathrm{A\,s}$.

The units work out the in the equivalency, which never requires breaking the coulomb into its base units, as follows:

- Newton: amount of force used when accelerating one kilogram at 1 meter per second squared, $$1\:\mathrm N = 1\mathrm{\frac{kg \, m}{s^2}}.$$
- Joule: energy transferred (or work done) when applying a force of one newton through a distance of one meter, $$1\:\mathrm J =1\:\mathrm{N \, m}.$$
- Volt: potential energy of one joule per electric charge of one coulomb, $$1\:\mathrm V = 1\:\mathrm{\frac{J}{C}}.$$
- Converting volts to joules per coulomb, then joules to newton-meters, then cancelling the meter, you get
  $$\mathrm{
  1\:\frac{N}{C} = 1\:\frac{V}{m} = 1\:\frac{J}{C \, m} = 1\:\frac{N \, m}{C \, m} = 1\:\frac{N}{C}.
  }$$

Comment: AFAIK, there is no such thing as a "fundamental unit" defined in SI. There are base units and derived units. The coulomb is a derived unit. The ampere and the second are base units, and 1 coulomb is equal to 1 amp-second. For more info, see the NIST [Guide for the use of SI](http://physics.nist.gov/cuu/pdf/sp811.pdf).

Comment: Ah! Thanks! Got amp and coulomb swapped in my head. Mind if I change my answer to match, or are you posting one?

Comment: For the record, current as a base unit is pretty unintuitive.

Comment: It is unintuitive. The questions I linked in commments on the OP ask about it explicitly.

Comment: Ah! Makes sense. What's a kg; the weight of that ball over there. What's an ampere; the current moving thru this. What's a Coulomb; well, count the number of particles moving thru the wire ... haha. Thanks for the links.

Answer (score 3):

The SI units for electromagnetism are [based on the ampere](http://physics.nist.gov/cuu/Units/current.html), which is

> that constant current which, if maintained in two straight parallel conductors of infinite length, of negligible circular cross-section, and placed 1 meter apart in vacuum, would produce between these conductors a force equal to $2\times10^{-7}$ newton per meter of length.

One coulomb is the amount of charge delivered by a current of one ampere when integrated over one second ($\rm 1\,C = 1\,A\cdot s$).

One volt is the electric potential difference across a device which consumes one watt of electrical energy when powered by a current of one ampere ($\rm 1\,V = 1\,\frac WA$).  This means that the volt is also equal to the electrical potential energy of one coulomb of charge ($\rm 1\,V = 1\,\frac{W\cdot s}{A\cdot s} = 1\,\frac JC$).

In your example,
$$
\rm 1\,\frac NC = 1\,\frac NC \frac mm = 1\,\frac JC \frac 1m = 1\,\frac Vm.
$$

Note that beginning in 2018 the SI units [will be overhauled to depend on fundamental constants](http://www.nist.gov/pml/newsletter/siredef.cfm). After the redefinition the coulomb will be defined as "the negative of the charge of $\frac{10^{19}}{1.602\cdots}$ electrons", where the first eight or nine significant digits of the denominator are already known.

Answer (score -1):

E=V/r=volt/meter   as volt=Joule/coulomb                                                     E=J/C.m            as J=N.m                                                                E=N.m/C.m    as m and m cancel each other                                              so,E=N/C